# How do I change the Bootstrap Navbar Dropdown Default down arrow icon?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, navbar

How do I change the default "down arrow" dropdown icon of Bootstrap Navbar?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdLJ3.png)

In the image above, I have displayed the arrow in red box.

Thank you for your help.

Pratik

I tried searching for appropriate CSS class that controls the item, but I did not find one.

Comment: Hello Pratik. Welcome to SO but SO is not code providing service. You should try something at your end and then come with tried code/demo so we can help you. Without any input from  yourside , we can't help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When you inspect the element using your browser dev tools, you can see that the "icon" is implemented via the `::after` pseudo element on the button. In its default form, it uses borders to create a "CSS triangle." If you want to replace it with something else, then overwrite the CSS for the pseudo element.